# UserInterface Oracle-SQLDeveloper

Tags: user-interface, oracle-sqldeveloper

I tell you the problem I have with SQL Developer.
I am working with Windows 10. My version of SQL Developer is: Version 19.2.1.247
Problem: I want to increase the size of the user interface menus.

I have read through the forums that this size can be modified in the file: ide.properties
The property is Ide.FontSize.
But the problem is that in my installation I can't find that file. The one I find is the ide-boot. Properties
And if in this file I add this property the application does not run.
Note: Do not confuse it with the font size of the code editor
Can you help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: That file is there, you just need help finding it. AppData is sometimes hidden in Explorer. We're you able to get as far as finding the system19.2... directory?

Comment: For me the file is in C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system19.2.1.247.2212\o.sqldeveloper

Comment: if you enable scaling at the OS level, SQLDev should respond to that as well https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/fixing-the-my-sql-developer-ui-is-so-tiny-problem/

Comment: Thank you very much. You were right. The file was hidden. The problem is solved